# safety of writing to struct member in signal handler

Tags: c, signals, c89

My question is:  Is it safe to write to a sig_atomic_t type in a signal handler if that is a member of a struct.

Consider the example case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct int_seen {
    sig_atomic_t usr1;
    sig_atomic_t term;
    sig_atomic_t client_term;
};

static volatile struct int_seen interrupts;

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    if (interrupts.term){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Considering that I am working on a multi-process but single threaded application, is it safe for a signal handler to write to interrupts.term etc?

Note the particular requirements of the code base I am working on is:

1. Must be C89 compliant
2. Is single threaded/multiprocess
3. Must be portable

I have tried reading the C89 standard and all I can see is that sig_atomic_t is the only type I can use, and that it is only guaranteed to be 8 bits at least in size.  I cannot figure out if this sort of usage is safe or not.

Comment: `sig_atomic_t` is an atomic data type wrt signal handlers. I do not see, why there should be a difference if the location of the corresponding variable is determined by being embedded in a structure.

Comment: I don't either but am asking.

Comment: Note that you also need to specify `volatile`.  Per [**A.6.2 Undefined behavior** of the C89 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#A.6.2): "A signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function, and the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the signal function itself or refers to any object with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to a static storage duration variable of type volatile sig_atomic_t"

Comment: So volatile must be added on the struct member as well as the struct allocation as a whole then, correct?  Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisTravers it is enough to add the volatile to the sig_atomic_t, as it always has to be.

Comment: The C standard is incredibly restrictive about what can be done in signal handlers, mainly because the lowest common denominator behaviour is very limited.  If you look at what POSIX permits, you find there are many more options and far fewer restrictions.  As noted by @AndrewHenle, according to the C standard, you can't access an element of a structure even if it is of type `sig_atomic_t`.  POSIX would let you access such structure members without problem; the onus is on you to ensure that there is no interference with other threads if your program is multithreaded.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, As I understand it the C99 committee noted that there were no known implementations that made reading a sig_atomic_t in a signal handler at that time problematic.  So while it is not C89 compliant in theory, it seems in practice to be safe.  But *writing* to a value from everything I have heard is not different just because it is a member of a struct.  If this is incorrect, please explain your comment as an answer.  I would love to get more info on this.

Comment: @ChrisTravers: The question of what can safely be done within a signal handler will depend upon what caused the signal to be raised.  Since the Standard doesn't define any means via which asynchronous signals can be raised, any situation where that could happen would be outside the jurisdiction of the Standard regardless of the types used in a signal handler.  Implementations running on anything other than 8-bit micros should be able to accommodate aligned objects of type any size up to `int` or `unsigned`.